# How to write correctly "redirect" (Spring MVC + Security)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I want in the project that after that the authorization happens, immediately go to the page where everything is for the student (redirect: / allStudents)
I kind of wrote everything, maybe I’m writing something wrong can tell

I have 2 controllers how to write redirect correctly

AuthorizationController

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class  AuthorizationController{

    // If user will be successfully authenticated he/she will be taken to the login secure page.
    @RequestMapping(value="/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView adminPage() {

        ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView();
        m.addObject("title", "Вы успешно вошли");
        m.addObject("message", "Основная");
        m.setViewName("admin");

                return new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");

    }

    // Spring security will see this message.
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error, 
            @RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout) {

        ModelAndView m = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            m.addObject("error", "Неверный логин и пароль");        
        }

        if (logout != null) {
            m.addObject("msg", "Вы успешно вышли");     
        }

        m.setViewName("login");

                 return new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");
    }
}
```

StudentController

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.entity.Student;
import adil.java.schoolmaven.service.StudentService;
import java.nio.file.FileSystemException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    // Constructor based Dependency Injection
    private StudentService studentService;

    public StudentController() {

    }

    @Autowired
    public StudentController(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }




    @RequestMapping(value = "/allStudents", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})

    public ModelAndView displayAllUser() {
        System.out.println("User Page Requested : All Students");
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAllStudents();
        mv.addObject("studentList", studentList);
        mv.setViewName("allStudents");
        return mv;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayNewUserForm() {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("addStudent");
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Add Student Details");
        mv.addObject("student", new Student());
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/addStudent")
    public String saveNewStudent(@RequestParam("name") @NonNull String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") @NonNull String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file)
            throws IOException {

        Student student = new Student();
        student.setSurname(surname);
        student.setName(name);

        if (file != null && !file.isEmpty()) {
            student.setAvatar(studentService.saveAvatarImage(file).getName());
        }

        studentService.saveStudent(student);
        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/editStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView displayEditUserForm(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("editStudent");
        Student student = studentService.getStudentById(id);
        mv.addObject("headerMessage", "Редактирование студента");
        mv.addObject("student", student);
        return mv;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/editStudent")
    public String saveEditedUser(
            @RequestParam("id") Long id,
            @RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("surname") String surname,
            @RequestParam("avatar") MultipartFile file) {

        try {

            studentService.updateStudent(name, surname, file, studentService.getStudentById(id));

        } catch (FileSystemException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "redirect:/error";
        }

        return "redirect:/allStudents";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/deleteStudent/{id}")
    public ModelAndView deleteUserById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        studentService.deleteStudentById(id);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");

        return mv;

    }

}
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:/allStudents");
return mv;
```

and

```
return "redirect:/allStudents";
```

are pretty the same. When you return a String in a controller, then it handled by ModelViewResolver. With ModelAndView you just force this step. 
For me it's more convenient to return simple String in return and use Model object for attributes. But it's quite an opinionated topic which is the best option and such topics are not allowed here. 
I think you should write like your team does and follow their code conventions. Peace!)